# OpenJpa enhancement of classes from external jar

Tags: java, spring, jpa, gradle, openjpa

I've created a gradle project `A` which consist only of entity classes like ...

```
@Entity
public class A {
    ...
}
```

Then I want to import it in another spring boot projects ex. `B C ...` which are using the same data model.

The problem is when I want to build the project using gradle I'm receiving that all those entity classes are not found by open jpa enhancer.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\abc\Desktop\...\A.class (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
        at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.AsmAdaptor.write(AsmAdaptor.java:58)
        at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCEnhancer.record(PCEnhancer.java:633)
        at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCEnhancer.record(PCEnhancer.java:619)
        at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCEnhancer.run(PCEnhancer.java:4904)
        at org.apache.openjpa.ant.PCEnhancerTask.executeOn(PCEnhancerTask.java:89)
        at org.apache.openjpa.lib.ant.AbstractTask.execute(AbstractTask.java:183)
...
```

The jar `A` is on the class path and there isn't any compilation errors.

Comment: check the project and build it again , it has not been built properly I guess

Comment: You mean to say you want to compile classes that are INSIDE a jar? Don't think that would ever work, since you can only enhance a CLASS file, not a class INSIDE a jar file. Unjar the jar and enhance

Comment: @NeilStockton how can I do this automatically ? I want to be able to modify the lib with entities and projects which need them can easily perform the update.

Comment: Do something with Gradle to unjar, enhance, and then re-jar. In which case tag your question as Gradle (which I dont use so can't help with that)